# How can I disable/enable my page action (Chrome Extension) programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing one Chrome Extension. Following my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Estensione",
  "description": "La mia estensione",

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "20": "img/img-20.png",
      "32": "img/img-32.png",
      "64": "img/img-64.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Titolo"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "declarativeContent",
    "identity",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

I need enable / disable my *page_action* based on the status of a web service. I've tried Chrome API [PageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) but without success; following the code (background.js):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

console.log("message: " + message.messageType);

// la popup della pageaction è stata visualizzata
if (message.messageType === 'popupLoaded') {
    // identifico il tab corrente
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {

        chrome.pageAction.hide(tab[0].id);
    });
}
});
```

Following my popup.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({messageType: 'popupLoaded'});
});
```

My expected result is that my extension is disabled when I click my popup.

How can I reach the goal?
Thanks

Comment: [chrome.pageAction.setPopup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setPopup) with an empty path for `popup` I guess?

Comment: What do you mean "without success"? What **exactly** are you seeing? Under what conditions did this not work? Given that the code you provided has a syntax error, it's clearly not your actual code. What is your code *actually* doing? Please provide an actual *complete*, but minimal, [MCVE] which duplicates the problem.

Comment: Hi, Exactly I would that my extension is disabled (ref: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).